# Why one property is not getting observable knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

Here is my full code.

When I run the program it is working but when I change the quantity value then subtotal is not getting changed.

If possible, could someone please go through my code and tell me which area I need to fix in the code?

### Full Code

```
    <table id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:150px">Product</th>
        <th>Price ($)</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Amount ($)</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody data-bind='template: {name: "orderTemplate", foreach: lines}'></tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="orderTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td><select data-bind='options: products,
                               optionsText: "name",
                               value: "id",
                               optionsCaption:"--Select--",
                               value: product'>
                               </select>
        </td>
        <td data-bind='with: product'>
            <span data-bind='text: formatCurrency(price)' ></span>
        </td>
        <td data-bind='with: product'>
            <input data-bind='value: quantity' />
        </td>
        <td ><span data-bind='text: formatCurrency(subtotal())'></span></td>
    </tr> 
</script>    

<script type="text/javascript">
    var _products = [
      {
          "name": "1948 Porsche 356-A Roadster",
          "price": 53.9,
          "quantity": 1
      },
      {
          "name": "1948 Porsche Type 356 Roadster",
          "price": 62.16,
          "quantity": 2
      },
      {
          "name": "1949 Jaguar XK 120",
          "price": 47.25,
          "quantity": 1
      },
      {
          "name": "1952 Alpine Renault 1300",
          "price": 98.58,
          "quantity": 1
      },
      {
          "name": "1952 Citroen-15CV",
          "price": 72.82,
          "quantity": 1
      },
      {
          "name": "1956 Porsche 356A Coupe",
          "price": 98.3,
          "quantity": 1
      },
      {
          "name": "1957 Corvette Convertible",
          "price": 69.93,
          "quantity": 1
      }];

      function formatCurrency(value) {
          return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
      }

      var CartLine = function () {
          var self = this;
          self.products = ko.observableArray(_products);
          self.product = ko.observable(1);
          self.price = ko.observable(1);
          self.quantity = ko.observable(1);   //default quantity value already defined in _products array
          self.subtotal = ko.computed(function () {
              //return self.product() ? self.product().price * parseInt("0" + self.product().quantity, 10) : 0;
              return self.price() * self.quantity();
          });

      };

      var Cart = function () {
          // Stores an array of lines, and from these, can work out the grandTotal
          var self = this;
          self.lines = ko.observableArray([new CartLine()]); // Put one line in by default
      };

      ko.applyBindings(new Cart());
</script>
```

Comment: well that's simple just try this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/24485/ . if all good i will post it as answer . cheers

Comment: @supercool yes thanks. this what i was looking for. nice jsfiddle link. u can post and i will mark as answer. thanks

Comment: never mind glad it helped as you already marked something as answer it wont be right i post it as answer . cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick summary, the Quantity textbox was populated by the selected product's quantity because of the *with* binding. The price observable had a static value of 1, now we got the selected price from the select element. Also, I think the quantity property is not needed in the _products array.

I have amended the following with comments,

> HTML

```
<table id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:150px">Product</th>
        <th>Price ($)</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Amount ($)</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody data-bind='template: {name: "orderTemplate", foreach: lines}'></tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/html" id="orderTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select data-bind='options: products, optionsText: "name", value: "id", optionsCaption:"--Select--", value: product'></select>
        </td>
        <td data-bind='with: product'>
            <span data-bind='text: formatCurrency(price)'></span>
        </td>
        // removed the data-bind here because it was getting the quantity assigned to the product
        // not from the input text box
        <td>
            <input data-bind='value: quantity, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
        </td>
        <td><span data-bind='text: subtotal()'></span></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

> JavaScript

```
    var _products = [
    {
        "name": "1948 Porsche 356-A Roadster",
        "price": 53.9,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "1948 Porsche Type 356 Roadster",
        "price": 62.16,
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "1949 Jaguar XK 120",
        "price": 47.25,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "1952 Alpine Renault 1300",
        "price": 98.58,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "1952 Citroen-15CV",
        "price": 72.82,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "1956 Porsche 356A Coupe",
        "price": 98.3,
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "1957 Corvette Convertible",
        "price": 69.93,
        "quantity": 1
    }];

function formatCurrency(value) {
    return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
}

var CartLine = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.products = ko.observableArray(_products);
    self.product = ko.observable(null); // set to null as it holds your selected product from the select element

    //self.price = ko.observable(1); do not this
    self.quantity = ko.observable(1);

    self.subtotal = ko.computed(function () {
        if (!self.product()) // on load self.product() will be null, return to avoid error
            return;
        // you get the select products price and multiple it by the quantity from the textbox
        return formatCurrency(self.product().price * self.quantity());
    });

};

var Cart = function () {
    // Stores an array of lines, and from these, can work out the grandTotal
    var self = this;
    self.lines = ko.observableArray([new CartLine()]); // Put one line in by default
};

ko.applyBindings(new Cart());
```

This works.

Thanks

Comment: this is missing `foreach: lines`

Comment: see this `<select data-bind='options: products, optionsText: "name", value: "id", optionsCaption:"--Select--", value: product'></select>` here u said value is id and also value is product is it correct ?

Comment: You can replace the script sections like-for-like

Comment: i have change my code as per your code but still amount is not changing when quantity change. same problem still persist. can u plzz include **jsfiddle** link of your rectified code.

Comment: Added all the code for you to copy, jsFiddle doesn't like me today.

Comment: why did u comment this line `//self.price = ko.observable(1);` i mean price property ?

Comment: Sorry, I should've removed it, it isn't being used. You get the price from the _products array. Did you get it to work?

Comment: one problem that quantity is not taking from product array ? rather it has been fixed....always one whenever select any data from drop down array.

Comment: I assumed that having a text box meant that you would want to change the quantity?

Comment: basically i want when user select data from dropdown then corresponding qty should be come and filled up in qty textbox and later user can change and accordingly amount should be change. so guide me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

i got a good answer from @Super Cool and i just modify his code a bit. like to share changed code here. here is jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/3bu6nybk/

```
<table id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:150px">Product</th>
        <th>Price ($)</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Amount ($)</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody data-bind='template: {name: "orderTemplate", foreach: lines}'></tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="orderTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td><select data-bind='options: products,
                               optionsText: "name",
                               optionsCaption:"--Select--",
                               value: product'>
                               </select>
        </td>

        <td>
            <span data-bind='text:price' ></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-bind='value:quantity' />
        </td>

        <td ><span data-bind='text:subtotal()'></span></td>

    </tr> 
</script>    

var _products = [
      {
          "name": "1948 Porsche 356-A Roadster",
          "price": 53.9,
          "quantity": 1
      },
      {
          "name": "1948 Porsche Type 356 Roadster",
          "price": 62.16,
          "quantity": 2
      },
      {
          "name": "1949 Jaguar XK 120",
          "price": 47.25,
          "quantity": 1
      },
      {
          "name": "1952 Alpine Renault 1300",
          "price": 98.58,
          "quantity": 1
      },
      {
          "name": "1952 Citroen-15CV",
          "price": 72.82,
          "quantity": 1
      },
      {
          "name": "1956 Porsche 356A Coupe",
          "price": 98.3,
          "quantity": 1
      },
      {
          "name": "1957 Corvette Convertible",
          "price": 69.93,
          "quantity": 1
      }];

       function formatCurrency(value) {
           alert(value.toFixed(2));
          return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
      }

      var CartLine = function () {
          var self = this;
          self.products = ko.observableArray(_products);
          self.product = ko.observable(1);
          self.price = ko.observable(1);
          self.quantity = ko.observable(1);   
          self.product.subscribe(function(item){
              if(!item)
              { 
                 self.price(0);
                 self.quantity(0);
                 return;
              }
             self.price(item.price);
             self.quantity(item.quantity);
          });

          self.subtotal = ko.computed(function () {

              return self.price() * self.quantity();
          },self);
      };

      var Cart = function () {
          // Stores an array of lines, and from these, can work out the grandTotal
          var self = this;
          self.lines = ko.observableArray([new CartLine()]); // Put one line in by default


      };

      ko.applyBindings(new Cart());
```